# What are these files? Why they cannot be turned on/off?

Tags: qgis, table

My question is why there are some layers which cannot be turned off?

[image: Anbau QGIS Files]

In my Google Earth project those were main maps and then other polygons/paths were, but In QGIS I am not able to turn them all off/on?

What am I doing wrong? I use QGIS 3.2 Bonn

Comment: They are tables without geometries. Right-click open attribute table

Comment: But why did they happened? I Imported my work from Google Earth, why it is not like happening like in Google Earth that is is acting like group

Comment: so the tables and polygons are grouped together?

Comment: You might get this if you have mixed geometries within one layer, or the importer stumbled over decimal point vs decimal comma.